Middleware Metadata Service - Google App Engine
I have the following sync service which is creating an error on a meta dataservice. Can I ask for help interpreting this? What is the meta dataservice? Is there a link to what this is doing? The error below appears when the service starts. This error prevents the sync service from starting
sync.yml

service: sync
instance_class: F2
automatic_scaling:
  max_instances: 1
runtime: python312
app_engine_apis: true
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT sync:app

#inbound_services:
#- warmup

libraries:
- name: jinja2
  version: latest
 - name: ssl
   version: latest

# taskqueue and cron tasks can access admin urls

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: sync.app
  secure: always
  redirect_http_response_code: 301

env_variables:
  MEMCACHE_USE_CROSS_COMPATIBLE_PROTOCOL: "True"
  NDB_USE_CROSS_COMPATIBLE_PICKLE_PROTOCOL: "True"
  DEFERRED_USE_CROSS_COMPATIBLE_PICKLE_PROTOCOL: "True"
  CURRENT_VERSION_TIMESTAMP: "1677721600"
 

sync.py 

import google.appengine.api

client = ndb.Client()
def ndb_wsgi_middleware(wsgi_app:disappointed_face:
    def middleware(environ, start_response:disappointed_face:
        with client.context():
            return wsgi_app(environ, start_response)

    return middleware


log that appears when service is starting
app.wsgi_app = ndb_wsgi_middleware(google.appengine.api.wrap_wsgi_app(app.wsgi_app))
2024-05-17 04:04:53 sync[20240515t183736] File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.12/site-packages/google/cloud/ndb/_datastore_query.py", line 373, in _next_batch
2024-05-17 04:04:53 sync[20240515t183736] response = yield _datastore_run_query(query)
2024-05-17 04:04:53 sync[20240515t183736] ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-05-17 04:04:53 sync[20240515t183736] File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.12/site-packages/google/cloud/ndb/tasklets.py", line 319, in _advance_tasklet
2024-05-17 04:04:53 sync[20240515t183736] yielded = self.generator.throw(type(error), error, traceback)
2024-05-17 04:04:53 sync[20240515t183736] ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-05-17 04:04:53 sync[20240515t183736] File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.12/site-packages/google/cloud/ndb/_datastore_query.py", line 1030, in _datastore_run_query
2024-05-17 04:04:53 sync[20240515t183736] response = yield _datastore_api.make_call(
2024-05-17 04:04:45 sync[20240515t183736] google.api_core.exceptions.RetryError: Maximum number of 3 retries exceeded while calling <function make_call..rpc_call at 0x3e956b7625c0>, last exception: 503 Getting metadata from plugin failed with error: Failed to retrieve http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/default/?recursive=true from the Google Compute Engine metadata service. Compute Engine Metadata server unavailable

Can you share detailed steps along with minimal code to replicate?

The above was my first attempt to create a unit that shows the unhappy path. Is there a link to documentation (and/or code) for what the metadata server is? That will help me make a focus searched as I cut the tree.

Are you searching for this document?
